# CSS3 pie not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, border, css3pie

I am trying to use CSS3 pie to allow for `border-radius` in IE 8. But guess what, it's not working.

Here's how I have been attempting to implement it:

```
#inner-orbit {
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -ms-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  behavior: url(../js/vendor/PIE.htc);
}
```

I have, of course, downloaded the .HTC file and have the correct path to it in the `url` part of the implementation.

I have also read the 'know issues' page for CSS3 pie and had no joy with the suggestions there.

Here is a link to a reproduction of the issue: [EXAMPLE LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/5LmPlQK72Mp8dyvJZrLS?p=preview)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All wizards are on vacations, so maybe you can show us a site with a problem? Otherwise we have only to guess. Also, tell us your OS and if you are testing on real IE8 or emulator.

Comment: should border radius not be **50%** (i.e. the max?)?

Comment: @MiheyEgoroff I am using a virtual machine (vm ware fusion) for testing in IE. I will try and get a fiddle/codepen together for you now

Comment: Thats bad news for you, I mean that you are using VM, cuz if you were using emulator that might be working on real IE. But anyway, try to reproduce the bug.

Comment: @MiheyEgoroff Do you think the problem could be a vm issue?

Comment: Yes, it might be. Still not sure, need to test in emulator. Last time I was using PIE about 2 year ago, even several times, and never met such problems.

Comment: @MiheyEgoroff If you haven't used PIE in 2 years, what do you use instead? I'm sure you still use border-radius? I am open to alternatives for getting border-radius working in IE 8.

Comment: No, I stop focusing on IE8. Graceful degradation or progressive enchantment, - the main goal/information should be visible and available on IE8, the effects are not necessary. Focus on modern browsers and make all info look at least good on old.

Comment: @MiheyEgoroff Ah right, ok. I need to support IE 8 (sadly) and without the border-radius in this particular instance the page looks wrong...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69206/discussion-between-mihey-egoroff-and-alan).

Comment: @MiheyEgoroff Ok, I have entered your chat.

Answer (score 1):

Please store your .htc file in default folder not in any folder i.e

```
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
```

Comment: Hi, this didn't change anything, sadly.

Comment: have you added pie.js file and loan conditionally for ie8

Comment: Yes, I have added the JS file and loaded conditionally.

Comment: i have a working example, i can share you please give me your mail you. I will send you.

Comment: Can you not provide it here?

Comment: I have hosted on cloud9. Check https://ide.c9.io/swapnilmotewar/css3pie     check in IE8 with inspect element you will get it

Comment: how can i give the whole folder to you from here??

Comment: Sorry, i thought you meant a link. I will create a Cloud9 account now and check, thanks

Comment: Doesn't seem to show rounded corners on your button in Cloud 9's IE 8 preview?

Comment: Please check this url in your browser ie8 https://css3pie-swapnilmotewar.c9.io/index.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69226/discussion-between-alan-and-swapnil-motewar).

Comment: That link is working, I will up-vote you. Can we move to chat?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [CSS3PIE documentation](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#relative-paths), the path to .htc must be set with regards to the HTML file, not your CSS file where the `url()` is written!
Simplest test case: put HTML, CSS and HTC in the same directory. If it works, then if your CSS is in `css/styles.css`, HTC too (`css/pie.htc`) and HTML in parent, then it'd be `behavior: url(PIE.htc);` and not `behavior: url(css/PIE.htc);`

Also I think I had problems with [.htc extension, Apache and mime type](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#content-type). Rename it to .js (EDIT: oops no, it's `.php`) or take care of correct mime type for this extension in your server.

Yeah, CSS3Pie is one of these tools where you'd better read thoroughly the documentation ;)

Comment: Hi @FelipeAls I will do as you suggested and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue must be with your behavior url path.

Comment: Why is that the case?